# Apache does not start after SSL installation

Tags: ssl, networking

[image]

When I am installing SSL on a server using putty, I start the server but it gives me an error like action start failed:

```
[Wed Jun 27 13:22:01.911656 2018] [ssl:emerg] [pid 18745] AH02312 Fatal error initialising mod_ssl, exiting.
[Wed Jun 27 13:30:53.196213 2018] [ssl:error] [pid 18832] AH02203: Init: Private key not found
[Wed Jun 27 13:30:53.196274 2018] [ssl:error] [pid 18832] SSL Library Error: error:0D07207B:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_get_object:header too long
[Wed Jun 27 13:30:53.196280 2018] [ssl:emerg] [pid 18832] AH02312: Fatal error initialising mod_ssl, exiting.
```

Comment: "Private key not found", so your configuration is wrong, and you do not show it at all, so noone can help you. Please do not use an image also, just put all relevant data as text in your question.

Comment: I have already done private key issue but its give same error i have above mention it